# Parameters Framework for C++

Tags: c++, open-source, parameters

I'm trying to find a parameters framework in C++ to synchronize parameters and variant types between a client/server.  I've tried googling around, but I think I don't have the right search terms.

Example: An object on the server could have the following parameters defined and mapped to the member variables:

```
"name":  std::string,
"alpha": float,
"mask":  uint
```

Where these parameters could then be queried by the client and their values adjusted.

Is there something similar to this that exists in the open source world?

Edit for clarification:

The server I've created is a video application, where a video is displayed with N number of filters.  The filters have N number of parameters, and are of different types.  I want the client to be able to query for: # of filters, the filter parameters, and those parameters types.

Comment: Is the Boost ['program options'](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options.html) library of any relevance?

Comment: hmm, boost program options might be a good start for me.  Thanks very much.  If you add an answer I'll set it as the answer.  I'm looking for a very very lightweight lib -- I'll be using OSC as the transport.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  And perhaps give another example? It's hard to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me rephrase.

What you want is a data exchange format between clients and servers written in C++ that lets you pass around structures known to both sides in an efficient and easy to process way, that hopefully lets you be upwards compatible so that you can upgrade server and client separately.

If so then http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ is Google's solution for this exact problem, used extensively internally.

Comment: By the way I've just been reading your blog, good stuff.  And brother of a WSOP champion! :)

Comment: Glad you like it, but it makes me feel old to realize that there is a generation now that mostly knows of her as a poker player.

Comment: Well, I was just commenting on your blog post about poker.  I ain't no spring chicken either unfortunately.  Either way, good stuff.